# Calling URL from SQL Agent, how do I get a response?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I'm successfully calling a URL via Operating System (CmdExec) in a multi step job, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a correct response to move onto the next step after calling the URL.

My job looks like this:

Step 1: SSIS package manipulates data.
Step 2: Call URL
Step 3: SSIS package manipulates data again.

The issue is, if I leave the successful process exit code as 0, the job fails on that step since the step doesn't generate any output (it generates a process exit code of 1).  If I change the successful process exit code to be 1, the job moves to step 3 before the URL portion is done running.  The URL part is going to be a variable amount of time every time it's run, so I can't put a set delay on that step.

For reference, this is how I'm calling the URL:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx"
```

Does anyone know of a way to make my second step wait until the URL is fully loaded before moving on to step 3?  I can make the URL output any sort of text if that's how it should be done.

Thanks

edit - Sorry, this was supposed to be posted in the DBA section but ended up in the Overflow section.

Comment: I think that you can use wget (for windows) to call the url and the program finish only after the url have successfully opened

Comment: What is the goal of opening the web page in IE?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I'm trying to get it to run a piece of code (ColdFusion) that another developer in my department created.  It's basically a piece of code that determines multi line orders vs. single orders in an application that was designed to only have single orders, but multi orders were required after it had been live for 2 months.

Comment: @bdn02 Thanks for sharing, I'm going to do some investigating to see if wget can do what I need.  In the meantime, I've split this into two jobs where I first call my first SSIS package, then run the CF code, then the job ends.  Once the CF code is done running, it calls the second job.  I'm going to use the suggestions here to try to get it back into one job.  I'll let you know if I have success with wget. Thanks

Comment: You could replace step 2 with some .NET code - either another SSIS package or a job step of PowerShell. There *is* a web service task in SSIS  but you can't control the timeout property on it so if it takes more than the default 3 or 6 minutes, you need to roll your own code.